# how get week numbers starting from sunday

Tags: excel

```
Date    Day_name  ****WeekNum****
1/1/2016    Fri     1
1/2/2016    Sat     1
1/3/2016    Sun     2
1/4/2016    Mon     2
1/5/2016    Tue     2
1/6/2016    Wed     2
1/7/2016    Thu     2
1/8/2016    Fri     2
1/9/2016    Sat     2
1/10/2016   Sun     3
1/11/2016   Mon     3
1/12/2016   Tue     3
1/13/2016   Wed     3
1/14/2016   Thu     3
1/15/2016   Fri     3
1/16/2016   Sat     3
1/17/2016   Sun     4
1/18/2016   Mon     4
1/19/2016   Tue     4
1/20/2016   Wed     4
1/21/2016   Thu     4
1/22/2016   Fri     4
1/23/2016   Sat     4
1/24/2016   Sun     5
1/25/2016   Mon     5
1/26/2016   Tue     5
1/27/2016   Wed     5
1/28/2016   Thu     5
1/29/2016   Fri     5
1/30/2016   Sat     5
1/31/2016   Sun     6
2/1/2016    Mon     6
2/2/2016    Tue     6
2/3/2016    Wed     6
```

Comment: start week day should be "sun" and end week day should be "Sat"

Answer (score 0):

Here Your starting week day should begin with sunday and the end day of week should be saturday

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your date in `A1` your `B1` and `C1` are as follows:

Day_name is `=TEXT(A1,"ddd")`

WeekNum starting on Sunday is `=WEEKNUM(A1,1)`